# Irreducibility of representations

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

I am trying to understand the attached solved example on irreducibility of a representation. The quoted example 4 has been put in pencil. I have not understood the underlined portions. Also what is the need to take sum and difference of Alpha and Beta? Will be grateful for clarification. [image]

Comment: It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: You need to have a look at your $Y$ to show that $(I-Y)x$ and $(I+Y)x$ cannot be both $0$ when $x\ne 0$.